# Why concurrently setting ivar makes bad access error?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstaggedpointerstring

I want to directly assign value to an ivar of class concurrently.

I know there will be problem using setter method (`self.target = ...`) since ARC inner retain and release stuff for `strong` property. **But I'm trying to use ivar.**

1. Is it because the implicit qualifier `__strong`? But `_target` is an ivar, so it won't be released outside each dispatch_async block, right?
2. And if you make the string shorter, iOS system will apply a tagged pointer to `_target`, why in this case no bad access error happens anymore?

```c
@interface ClassA ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *target;
@end

@implementation ClassA
- (void)test {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("parallel", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            _target = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa-%d",i];  //Bad Access Error in releasing, an NSCFString
            //_target = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aa-%d",i];  //No problem, an NSTaggedPointerString
        });
    }
}
@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    [obj test];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ivar` doesn't makes difference: compiler just add retain/release instead of you. You need `unsafe_unretained` property to disable insertion of retain/release

Comment: I can understand retain, for [NSString stringWithFormat:...] will be autoreleased later, so _target has to retain it. But where does release happen? When it go outside the block scope? But _target is an instance variable, why could it be released outside the block scope?

Comment: According to some blog, setter method is the spot where new value retaining and old value releasing happen. But I also learn that assign value to a strong variable will invoke `objc_storeStrong` function, where implicit retain and release codes locate. So where on earth is retain/release happen, setter or process of value assign to ivar?

Comment: @刘maxwell, in the assign new value will be retained and old will be released, you can look at inserted retain/release calls in the assembler